# How to run prediction model

Tags: sas, predict

Is there an equivalent of R's function `predict(model, data)` in SAS?

For example, how would you apply the model below to a large test data set where the response variable "Age" is unknown?

```
proc reg data=sashelp.class;
    model Age = Height Weight ;
run;
```

I understand you can extract the formula Age = Intercept + Height(Estimate_height) + Weight(Estimate_weight) from the results window and manually predict "Age" for unknown observations, but that's not very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS does this by itself. As long as the model has enough data points to go on, it will output the predicted value. I've used proc glm, but you can use any model procedure to create this kind of output.

```
/* this is a sample dataset */
data mydata;
input age weight dataset $;
cards;
1 10 mydata
2 11 mydata
3 12 mydata
4 15 mydata
5 12 mydata
;
run;

/* this is a test dataset. It needs to have all of the variables that you'll use in the model */
data test;
input weight dataset $;
cards;
6 test
7 test
10 test
;
run;
/* append (add to the bottom) the test to the original dataset */
proc append data=test base=mydata force; run;

/* you can look at mydata to see if that worked, the dependent var (age) should be '.' */
/* do the model */
proc glm data=mydata;
model age = weight/p clparm; /* these options after the '/' are to show predicte values in results screen - you don't need it */
output out=preddata predicted=pred lcl=lower ucl=upper; /* this line creates a dataset with the predicted value for all observations */
run;
quit;

/* look at the dataset (preddata) for the predicted values */
proc print data=preddata;
where dataset='test';
run;
```